# Why cut action doesn't work on EditBox in c#/xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, cut, editbox

I've got a strange issue. Ctrl+x (only cut part. copy and paste works fine) doesn't work (on my computer) on EditBox in c#/xaml. I tried it with a fresh new xaml project with only 2 EditBox in it. I generate an exe and send it to people in my company and people in former company. In former company ctrl+x works fine. In my company it's not working for people next to me but it's work for coleague in other country. I tried it on windows 11 and windows 10. If someone already met this issue or have a clue ... i take :)

Here is my xaml and there is no code behind.

```
<Window x:Class="TestCutCopyPaste.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCutCopyPaste"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="200" />
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Grid.Row="1" Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was finally found. The issue was due to Sysmon tools (security tool recently install in my company) which interfer with the cut/copy/paste